# sum of any four number always one in C#

Tags: c#, rounding

always one is the result of sum four numbers that less than one.

1. i changed the number to decimal and float
2. i used math,truncate
3. i wrote double before each number in calculation

still the result of sum is one

this my code and I added comment in the code in the place of my quistion

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm3 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public double[,] array = new double[4, 4];
        public double b1vsb1c1=1.0;
        public double b1vsb2c2;
        public double b1vsb3c3;
        public double b1vsb4c4;
// //  .....here cotinue declear variable ,I deleteed to  shoritng the code;                  

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string isChecked2 = RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();

            if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "1")
            {
                b1vsb1c1 = 1.0;
                b2vsb1c1 = 1.0;
            }

            else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "3")
            {
                b1vsb2c2 =3.0;
                b2vsb1c1 =1.0/3.0;
            }
            
            //  .....here cotinue test radio button value ,I deleteed to  shoritng the code;                 
                array[0,0]=b1vsb1c1;
                array[0,1]=b1vsb2c2;
                //....here cotinue assign value to array ,I deleteed to  shoritng the code;           
                
           
                        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                        {
                             sum = 0.0;
                             av = 0.0;
                            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                            {
                                sum=(double)sum + (double)array[i,j];
                               
                               
                            }
                            // here the sum always one why?!!
                            
                            av = (double)sum/(double)4.0;
                            Response.Write(av + "|   |");
                            // here is always result 0.25 why?
                        }
                        

             }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give us previous codes.

Comment: What's the type of p1

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Naila What are the values in variables p1,p5,p9,p13?

Comment: I'm sure that double arithmetic is operating correctly, so I would start by checking your code prior to `double sum = ...` and make sure your inputs are the correct values.  Perhaps output the numbers before you sum them to check their values, or walk through with the debugger.

Comment: Using the initial values in comments and trying your code I get `sum=0.374247894103491` and `avg1=0.0935619735258728` Could you explain how do you get/check the values mentioned in your question?

Comment: @Turtle sorry for that .here is my full code

Comment: @Rusty it is numbers less than one . i updted the quistion and add my code.

Comment: @nvoigt  I exeplained more and added comment in the code that specify the place of quistion

Comment: @Dan-o I exeplained more and added comment in the code that specify the place of quistion

Comment: @AstroCB I exeplained more and added comment in the code that specify the place of quistion

Comment: @Chris Pietschmann I exeplained more and added comment in the code that specify the place of quistion

Comment: @Piyush I exeplained more and added comment in the code that specify the place of quistion

Comment: That for sure is not the shortest code you could have. Shorten your code, remove the parts that are irrelevant to your error.

Comment: @nvoigt i;m so sorry for this.now I deleted any part i think that not the reason of the problem

Answer (score 2):

Try to use an [`Implicit typing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) : var to declare your varibales
I tried what you said; I have logic result : here is a sample exmaple:

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var p1 = 0.120336943441637;
            var p5 = 0.01323706377858;
            var p9 = 0.120336943441637;
            var p13 = 0.120336943441637;
            var sum = p1 + p5 + p9 + p13;
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
        }

    }
```

**Result = 0.374247894103491**

[Code Run](http://rextester.com/POKZ43417)

Comment: i can confirm i get the same eg. not 1 and 0.25

Comment: Can you explain why Implicit Typing should be the answer at the question?

Comment: Well since the decalred variable type not mentioned, I suggest use implicit typing cause the var keyword let the compiler choose  the type of the variable from the expression on the right side of the initialization statement.

Comment: @MoezRebai sorry for that. i updted the quistion and add my code

Comment: @MoezRebai i do it but still the same result .

Comment: @ThomasAndreèLian i'm a begginer. maybe my error not here i updted the quistion and add my code